# If $|B| \geq 2$, prove or disprove that $|A \times B| \geq |B|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I've tried to prove this using proof by contradiction:

Claim: $|A \times B| \lt |B|$.

Let $B$ be a subset of an infinite set $A$ and $f: B \to B \times B$ be a surjective function. Then $|B| \le |B \times B| \le  |B| \le |A|$. In this case, since the cardinality of B is less or equal to A, the product of the two will be more than B itself.
Therefore, our claim is false and the original claim is true.

Is this a proper approach to this question? Is there a better, more direct proof that I can use?

Comment: $\varnothing\times B=\varnothing$.

Comment: Did you mean to assume $|A|\ge2$? (In light of the latest edit I suspect not, but if you did even $|A|\ge1$ would have worked.)

Comment: @J.G. The question states $|B| \geq 2$. Would the claim be false then?

Comment: How would you know that $\ngeq$ implies $<$?

Comment: there is an injection $B\to A\times B$,whenever $A\neq \emptyset$

Comment: @AsafKaragila You're right. That was a wrong assumption on my part.